# Лебедь, тюль и прочие спорные случаи

Tags: морфология

Читала о таком случае: "Недавно в одной из школ на уроке русского языка детям задали определить род существительных. Слово «лебедь» дети определили как существительное мужского рода, а учительница исправила на женский".
Так какого же рода слово "лебедь"? А еще часто женским родом обозначают слова "тюль", а иногда еще и шампунь. Но при этом в роде таких слов, как "соль", "консоль", "бемоль" никто не сомневается. Как получилось, что такие однотипные слова имеют разный род?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В русском языке существительные с мягким нулевым окончание могут быть как женского, так и мужского рода, хотя м.род встречается реже (в основном на сонорный согласный): конь, зверь, король. Поэтому род заимствованных слов - это не общая тенденция, а индивидуальная история в каждом случае.

ЛЕБЕДЬ 
Сегодня слово "лебедь" относится к мужскому роду. Употребление его в женском роде считается устаревшим, но допускается в народной речи и в поэзии: «Глядь – поверх текучих вод Лебедь белая плывет».

ТЮЛЬ  - слово мужского рода французского происхождения (tulle), и во французском языке оно мужского рода! Тюль - это ткань, названная так в честь французского города Тюль, где и был изготовлен первый тюль.

ШАМПУНЬ  - слово происходит от английского shampoo – "мыть голову".  Большинство современных словарей определяет род этого существительного как мужской, это и является общеупотребительной нормой в русском языке. Род шампуни могли изменить в 2009 году, но все-таки оставили без изменения. Хотя у Даля: Шампунь ж., ароматическая жидкость для мытья головы; также и самый процессъ мытья головы этою жидкостью. В «Толковый словаре русского языка Ушакова Д.Н.» (вышедшем позже словаря В.И. Даля)  слово «шампунь» может быть как женского, так и мужского рода.

Answer (score 0):

Слово "лебедь" относится ко второму склонению, т. к. вопрос "он мой". А во втором склонении слова мужского рода без окончания и слова среднего рода с окончаниями "е", "э". Это же не средний род? Значит, "лебедь" мужского рода.
Информация о слове: изм. по числ., изм. по пад., обозначает предмет - имя существительное. Начальная форма - кто? И. п. - лебедь.
Постоянные признаки - м. р., 2 скл.
Форма, в которой слово употреблено - ед. ч., И. п.